# IdentityServer4 Version="4.1.1" MTLS configuration services.AddAuthentication().AddCertificate not working

Tags: identityserver4, mtls

Problem with Startup.cs setup, according to documentation I should add

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    });
```

But I got error:

> 'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddCertificate' and  there is no extension method 'AddCertificate'.

In samples code setup `IdentityServer(HOST)/ConsoleMTLSClient` it works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate/) NuGet package.

Comment: Great! Does this make the answer an acceptable answer?